# How can i make the rectangle print empty?

Tags: c, rectangles

Im trying to print a hollow rectangle. But it wont print out right. This is what i have so far. It prints but not a hollow rectangle. It makes random integers between 50 and 1.

```
void randomRectangle(){

srand(time(NULL));

int counter = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
int height = rand() % 50;
int width = rand() % 50;


printf("Now printng a rectangle.\n");
printf("Height = %d\n" "Width = %d\n", height, width);

while(counter < height){
counter++;
counter2 = 0;
        while(counter2 < width){
                if (((counter2 > 1)&&(counter2 < height))&&((counter > 1)&&(counter < height))){
                printf("  ");
                }
                else if((counter2 != 0)&&(counter != 0)){
                printf("* ");
                }

counter2++;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

counter2 is goes for width, but you're comparing it with height, here is proper loop for you solution:

```
while(counter < height)
{
    counter2 = 0;
    while(counter2 < width)
    {
        if ( ((counter > 0)&&(counter < (height-1))) && ((counter2 > 0)&&(counter2 < (width-1))) )
            printf("  ");
        else
            printf("* ");
        counter2++;
    }
    counter++;
    printf("\n");
}
```

note - it is not optimal solution, but if you're trying to make some exercise based on sample  - its ok

Answer (score 0):

There is also another problem with your code. The heights and widths of your rectangles will be between 0 and 49. rand() will return a number between 0 and RAND_MAX. The following correction will produce random numbers between 1 and 50.

```
int height = rand() % 50 + 1;
int width = rand() % 50 + 1;
```